# In/not in for the date

Tags: sql, excel, vba

My code is:

```vb
 RECSET.Open "select isin.LB_LONG from DB_RGA isin, DB_VALEUR_RGA val" & _
                " where isin.CD_RGA = '" & Code_Isin & "' and isin.IS_RGA=val.IS_RGA and (val.D_COTATION in ('28/08/2020','') or val.D_COTATION > '13/10/2020') and val.D_COTATION not in ('17/10/2020')", cnn_Pefase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
```

I need to chose the date that is `28/08/2020` or `missing value` or  `> 13/10/2020` but not `17/10/2020`.

Comment: Deleted my answer, you did not miss parentheses. Use NULL instead of ''

Comment: Use a parametrized query.

Comment: What is parametrized query?

Comment: See https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx?m=1